# OleDbDataAdapter Fill() out of memory

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I need to Read Excel to DB, but when I run to Fill() will error：System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: out of memory / full memory

```
using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 10 [titleName] FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))  
{  
    DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();  
    oda.Fill(dtExcelData);  
}
```

When I open excel in local and save, then run again this code will work, I don't know why?
My work need to auto run, so I can't open excel everytime.

this excel is from Email, I use imap

Comment: Have you tried using the IMEX=1 extended property in the connection string. This can help prevent "out of memory" errors by causing the driver to always treat input values as text, regardless of the cell format. e.g. `string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\file.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;'";`

Comment: Yes, my app.config already use IMEX=1.`<add name ="Excel07+ConString"
    connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'"/>`

Comment: Can you change your code so that you iterate over the excel lines instead using `fill()` method?

Comment: Additionally there are some packages for reading excel files: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader and https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I ended up using NPOI to read Excel, but I still think it's not the best.